# Single Spark Streaming consumer to listen to multiple HDFS directories

Tags: hdfs, spark-streaming

I am aware that Spark Streaming consumer can listen to a HDFS directory.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/home/hadoop/spark/conf:/home/hadoop/conf:/home/hadoop/spark/classpath/emr/*:/home/hadoop/spark/classpath/emrfs/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-lzo.jar")

val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))
ssc.checkpoint("/name/spark-streaming/checkpointing")

val lines = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs:///name/spark-streaming/data/")
```

But, I would like to know if the the same Streaming consumer can listen to multiple HDFS directories.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this.. I am also looking for listening from multiple folders in sparkstreaming.